# How to know How many times function is called without declaring variable outside function

Tags: javascript, function

This is the sample function I want to know how many times it is called inside the function without declaring variable outside the function. Actually it is nested function when I call the parent the outside function is redeclared. I want to avoid it.

If there is something in modern javascript from which we can get how many times it is called.

```
fn(){
}

fn()
```

Comment: *"Actually it is nested function when I call the parent the outside function is redeclared. I want to avoid it."* Avoid *what*? The function being recreated? If it's created inside another function, you can't avoid that. Please provide more context with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with declaring a variable outside of the function. It's exactly what you *should* do. Why are you trying to avoid it?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing built into JavaScript that tells you how many times a function has been called. If you want that information, you have to store it somewhere that persists beyond the duration of the function call — e.g., a variable outside the function, or similar.

**A variable specifically for this purpose outside the function would be best practice if possible,** but you've said you don't want one (or can't have one), so a **very much less ideal** approach would be to store the information on the function itself. Functions are objects, which means you can add properties to them:

```
function fn() {
    fn.callCount = (fn.callCount || 0) + 1;
    // ...
}
```

Inside a function, its name is in scope as an identifier, referring to the function. So the code above gets the value of a `callCount` property from the function (defaulting it to `0` if it isn't there or has a falsy value), then sets the property to that value plus one.

That will only count the number of times **that** function was called. You said your function was nested. I couldn't tell from your question whether you wanted to know the *total* calls to the function, or the calls to that *version* of the function created by the call to the parent function. The above give you the latter. If you want the former, you could store the information on the parent function:

```
function parent() {
    function fn() {
        parent.fnCallCount = (parent.fnCallCount.callCount || 0) + 1;
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

**But again**, I don't recommend it if you can avoid it. Use a dedicated variable if you can.

Live Examples:

```js
function parent1() {
    function fn() {
        fn.callCount = (fn.callCount || 0) + 1;
        // ...
        console.log(`fn calls so far: ${fn.callCount}`);
    }
    fn();
    fn();
    fn();
}

console.log("Tracking on fn itself:");
parent1();
// fn calls so far: 1
// fn calls so far: 2
// fn calls so far: 3
parent1();
// fn calls so far: 1
// fn calls so far: 2
// fn calls so far: 3

function parent2() {
    function fn() {
        parent2.fnCallCount = (parent2.fnCallCount || 0) + 1;
        // ...
        console.log(`fn calls so far: ${parent2.fnCallCount}`);
    }
    fn();
    fn();
    fn();
}

console.log();
console.log("Tracking on the parent itself:");
parent2();
// fn calls so far: 1
// fn calls so far: 2
// fn calls so far: 3
parent2();
// fn calls so far: 5
// fn calls so far: 4
// fn calls so far: 6
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Using a variable (I realize you've said you don't want to or can't, but for others, and as an alternative...):

```js
function parent1() {
    let fnCallsInner = 0;
    function fn() {
        ++fnCallsInner;
        // ...
        console.log(`fn calls so far: ${fnCallsInner}`);
    }
    fn();
    fn();
    fn();
}

console.log("Tracking on fn itself:");
parent1();
// fn calls so far: 1
// fn calls so far: 2
// fn calls so far: 3
parent1();
// fn calls so far: 1
// fn calls so far: 2
// fn calls so far: 3

let fnCallsOuter = 0;
function parent2() {
    function fn() {
        ++fnCallsOuter;
        // ...
        console.log(`fn calls so far: ${fnCallsOuter}`);
    }
    fn();
    fn();
    fn();
}

console.log();
console.log("Tracking on the parent itself:");
parent2();
// fn calls so far: 1
// fn calls so far: 2
// fn calls so far: 3
parent2();
// fn calls so far: 5
// fn calls so far: 4
// fn calls so far: 6
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```